# Extract a substring by using regex doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, string, text-extraction

I have a string like this:

```
String source = "https://1116.netrk.net/conv1?prid=478&orderid=[6aa3482b-519b-4127-abee-debcd6e39e96]"
```

I want to extract orderid which is inside [ ]. I wrote this method:

```
public String extractOrderId(String source)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[(.*?)]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    if (m.find())
        return m.group(1);
    else
        return "";
}
```

But I always get Exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape brackets:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
```

Comment: You need to escape the regex... Not java string.. Its more like `"\\[(.*?)\\]"`

Comment: @AbishekManoharan, you're right, it works with "\\[(.*?)\\]"

Comment: Sorry, some confusion about escaping ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using a regex you could use the URL class to extract the query:

```
URL url = new URL("https://1116.netrk.net/conv1?prid=478&orderid=[6aa3482b-519b-4127-abee-debcd6e39e96]");
String query = url.getQuery();
```

At that point the value of query is `prid=478&orderid=[6aa3482b-519b-4127-abee-debcd6e39e96]`. From there you can easily extract the `orderid` by a combination of `indexOf` and `substring`.

```
String searchFor = "orderid=[";
int fromIndex = query.indexOf(searchFor);
int toIndex = query.indexOf("]", fromIndex);

//6aa3482b-519b-4127-abee-debcd6e39e96
String orderId = query.substring(fromIndex+searchFor.length(), toIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx is lack of `\\`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use escape characters for [] , try the following

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `[(.*?)]`. Please refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the meaning of square brackets.

So in this case, you need to define the regex for the character `[` and `]` as well. So you need to escape those characters from the `Pattern.compiler`.

The following will match the requirement that you want.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
```